# AWK: How to use OFS ignoring blank and commented out lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to rewrite a file on the fly, like this:

```
10.213.20.173, mem_chld, p3b-aggr-103, c3.xlarge, db, mysql
#10.213.20.191, mem_leaf, p3b-leaf-101, r3.xlarge, db, mysql
10.213.20.192, mem_leaf, p3b-leaf-102, r3.xlarge, db, mysql

10.213.20.190, mem_leaf, p3b-leaf-103, r3.xlarge, db, mysql
.....
```

from the original `,` separated filed to a `:` separated ones. So, I used this:

```
awk -F', ' 'BEGIN{OFS=":";} { $1=$1; print }'
```

which is pretty much working but that file also has some blank and commented out lines, which I also want to exclude. My attempt with:

```
awk -F', ' '!/^(#|$)/ {OFS=":";} { $1=$1; print }'
```

did not work as I expected. How can I do that? Best!

Comment: Could you add an actual example of "commented out" line?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: edited my OP to reflect the "blank" and "commented" lines.

Comment: Its worrying that you thought replacing `BEGIN` with `!/^(#|$)/` might work for you and to a lesser extent that you didn't know you could set `OFS` using `-v`. That indicates a complete lack of understanding of awk fundamentals. You should really read at least the first couple of chapters of the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins if you're considering doing anything else with awk.

Comment: @Ed Morton: I DID NOT think it will work in I remove BEGIN, it's just one of the things I tried when I ram out of ideas. Thanks for the book. "complete lack of understanding of awk" may be a little harsh but hey, we all go though the "learning phase" - right? and I agree I need to do some more reading on AWK. Best!

Comment: Sorry if it came across as harsh, but THE fundamental thing you need to know about awk is that each script is a series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements, and you specifically said that when you replaced the `BEGIN` condition with a condition you wanted applied to every line it `did not work as I expected` which sounds to me like you were just shuffling bits of code around with no idea of what they did or why they had to be in specific locations. Anyway, that book is THE best resource for learning awk besides lurking in the comp.lang.awk newsgroup so all the best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F', ' 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} !/^#/ && NF{$1=$1; print}' file
10.213.20.173:mem_chld:p3b-aggr-103:c3.xlarge:db:mysql
10.213.20.192:mem_leaf:p3b-leaf-102:r3.xlarge:db:mysql
10.213.20.190:mem_leaf:p3b-leaf-103:r3.xlarge:db:mysql
```

alternatively you can set `OFS` like:

```
awk -F', ' -v OFS=':' '!/^#/ && NF{$1=$1; print}' file
```

or even

```
awk -F', ' '!/^#/ && NF{$1=$1; print}' OFS=':' file
```

As [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263981/awk-how-to-use-ofs-ignoring-blank-and-commented-out-lines/25264354#comment39368464_25264354) suggested in the comments, for an edge case where you might have space before the `#` it is best to use the following:

```
awk -F', ' 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} !/^[[:space:]]*#/ && NF{$1=$1; print}' file
```

**Explanation:**

`$1=$1` rebuilds the `$0` variable. It takes all the fields and concatenates them, separated by `OFS` which we have set to `:` instead of space which is the default.

Comment: Could you explain the `NF{ ... }` bit pleas?

Comment: @MacUsers Sure, `NF` is an `awk` built-in variable that is set to number of fields. Keeping `NF` as a condition allows us to skip over empty lines since `NF` value for empty lines is 0 effectively making it false for them.

Comment: +1 but `!/^[[:space:]]*#/...` might be safer in case there's ever leading white space before the comment start symbol.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, have added your suggestion to the answer. Ironic that being a tester, I didn't even think about that. Thanks for watching my back as always. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
awk -F', ' -v OFS=':' '/^[^#]/ {$1=$1; print}' datafile
```

This will ignore both empty lines and lines *starting* with a `#` sign.

If comments might be preceded by some spaces, you would prefer:

```
awk -F', ' -v OFS=':' '!/^[ \t]*(#.*)?$/ {$1=$1; print}' datafile
```

Comment: Did not know `OFS` can be used with `-v` switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F', ' -v OFS=: '/^[ \t]*(#|$)/{next}{$1=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
10.213.20.173:mem_chld:p3b-aggr-103:c3.xlarge:db:mysql
10.213.20.192:mem_leaf:p3b-leaf-102:r3.xlarge:db:mysql
10.213.20.190:mem_leaf:p3b-leaf-103:r3.xlarge:db:mysql
```